# Connecting list of case classes to kafka producer?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, alpakka

I have the below case class:

```
case class Alpakka(id:Int,name:String,animal_type:String)
```

I am trying to connect a list of these case classes to a producer in kafka by using the following code:

```
  def connectEntriesToProducer(seq: Seq[Alpakka]) = {


    val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")

seq.map(alpakka => new ProducerRecord[String, String]("alpakkas", alpakka.asJson.noSpaces))   
      .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
  }
```

I am using circe to convert the case class to json.  However I keep getting a compiler error saying this:

```
Error:(87, 34) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord[String,String],scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done]]
 required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord[String,String] => ?
      .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
```

I'm not sure whats going on!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a `Graph` from a `Seq` instead of a `Source`.

Your method `connectEntriesToProducer` should look like

```
def connectEntriesToProducer(seq: Source[Alpakka]) = {
```

Note, `Source` instead of `Seq`.

In alternative, you can build a source from a `Seq`, but you'll have to use `immutable.Seq` since `Source.apply` would only take an immutable iterable.

```
def connectEntriesToProducer(seq: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Alpakka]) = {
val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
  .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")

Source(seq).
  map(alpakka => new ProducerRecord[String, String]("alpakkas", alpakka.asJson.noSpaces))
  .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
}
```